# command-not-found not working because programs.sqlite is missing

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm on the unstable nix channel:

```
# nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable
# nix-channel --update
downloading Nix expressions from ‘https://nixos.org/releases/nixos/unstable/nixos-16.09pre78848.9549257//nixexprs.tar.xz’...
downloading ‘https://nixos.org/releases/nixos/unstable/nixos-16.09pre78848.9549257//nixexprs.tar.xz’... [ [6192/6921 KiB, 6143.1 KiB/s]
unpacking channels...
```

For some reason, `command-not-found` doesn't work:

```
$ command-not-found
/home/fabian command-not-found 
DBI connect('dbname=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/programs.sqlite','',...) failed: unable to open database file at /run/current-system/sw/bin/command-not-found line 13.
cannot open database `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/programs.sqlite' at /run/current-system/sw/bin/command-not-found line 13.
```

Indeed, /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/programs.sqlite doesn't exist. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's removed in the most recent channels/nixos builds and awaiting a replacement - refs ([1](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/12044)) ([2](https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-channel-scripts/issues/4))

Comment: these github issues are sometimes hard to find... thank you (even if it's not the answer I was hoping for)

Comment: Yes the nixOS repos sure are busy. As for the command-not-found program it's not present on non-nixOS systems anyway. That's the case for my native system. I use nix-env with the `-qas` flags to check package availability, perhaps that would be a helpful substitute in this case also.

Comment: well, I liked it to determine which package contains an executable. I also liked the brand new feature of `NIX_AUTO_RUN`. But well, that's life. For the nix-env command, I would add `-P` to get the attribute path.

Comment: It's now back in action.

Comment: Disabled another time and apparently fixed again (though probably not yet available): https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-channel-scripts/issues/9

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, it seems `nixos-install` doesn't properly generate `programs.sqlite`.

I was seeing the same error on a fresh 17.03 install, even though it's working on other systems I have that are also on 17.03.

Manually running `nix-channel --update` was all that was needed to fix it for me. (I didn't run `nixos-rebuild` or anything that would have changed the versions of `command-not-found`.)

Comment: I had to run with `sudo`. `sudo nix-channel --update`